# How to disable portrait orientation for Ipad in swift 2 and xcode 7

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-orientation

I have been having this issue with the layout orientations specifically with ipads. In xcode, I clicked on the project itself in the left panel and disabled portrait layout. This worked for iphones and ipods but not ipads. The application is run on any ipad, the portrait mode is enabled. When turned to the portrait orientation in an ipad, my layout gets squished together and looks very bad. Is there anyway I would be able to only allow the devise orientation to be landscape on every device?

[Here is a screenshot of the settings I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHuIa.png)

Comment: Select iPad with the device drop-down menu and turn off two portrait checkboxes.

Comment: thanks loads (: works perfectly